# Global class instance/object to be used throughout all website

Tags: php, oop, global

I'm designing a PHP application, which needs one class instance per user per session to be available on all scripts/pages. Moreover, that instance needs to be updated as updates might be addressed from time to time. Is there a way to do it in any other way except serializing an object and putting it into $_SESSION?

Comment: Even session won't do this if you mean that every different user needs access to it. Use a database.

Comment: Nope, I mean the single user in a single session. Updated my question.

Comment: Okay, in that case, sessions still aren't the right option (imo). While you can hijack session data in some circumstances, it's dodgy at best. Database / Memcache / Redis for persistent storage that you can query with each request is probably the more sensible way to go.

Comment: Per logged in user or all user sessions? If one  user starts two sessions in different browsers? what do you expect to happen? just curious, Why is it important to have: _'one class instance per user per session to be available on all scripts/pages.'_ i.e. what issue are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to minimize the amount of processing. Lets say we have a script page which handles user authentication and upon success it creates an instance of user object with its variables and methods. The same script redirects to another page/script that needs the same instance of the same class and so on. No actual user needs to access instance of user class other than its own. I simply know whether its possible to make object visible in the same scope as $_SESSION variable.